# Number Format Exception in java but format is true

Tags: java, string, double, numberformatexception

```
List<Person> list=new ArrayList<Person>();
public List<Person> readFile(){
    File file =new File("dosya.txt");
    try {
        FileReader fileReader=new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        while(reader.readLine()!=null){
            String personData= reader.readLine();
            System.out.println(personData);
            Person person=new Person();
            person.setName(personData.substring(1,personData.indexOf("#")));
            String sayı=personData.substring(personData.indexOf("#")+1,personData.indexOf("#",personData.indexOf("#")+1));

            person.setMoney(Double.valueOf(sayı));
            personData=personData.substring(personData.indexOf("#")+1);
            System.out.println(personData);
            person.setRate(Double.valueOf(personData.substring(0,3)));
            personData=personData.substring(personData.indexOf("#")+1);
            System.out.println(personData);
            person.setNumber(Short.valueOf(personData));
            list.add(person);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is my code and it seperate "fsyxaimvct wdyeyttuye#1528640,88#0,7#9"
this type of data and it gives mi error like that

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2273370,68"
at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2054)
at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:549)
at java.base/java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:512)
at FileProcess.readFile(FileProcess.java:19)
at Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

Why this cant turn 2273370,68 to double

Comment: Educated guess: The machine locale has a decimal separator of `.` (not `,`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. it works. I am the one creating data with random format so i never think it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`Double.valueOf()` doesn't 'do' locale - it parses specifically only numbers that use `.` as decimal separator. Your input string contains a comma which means it'll fail.

But, this code is essentially useless. You can't do currency with doubles - doubles are imprecise and will silently round. This is not what you want when working with currency.

The simplest solution is to store the 'atomic unit' for the currency. For dollars, store dollarcents. For bitcoin, store satoshis. For yen, store yen. For english pounds, store pennies. And so on. In a `long`, or if you must, a `BigInteger`.

Alternatively, use a library (`joda-currency` is a good one). You'll often hear advice to use `BigDecimal` but this is usually a bad idea (it's got all sorts of hairy complications; for example, You can't divide BigDecimals at all unless you really know what you are doing - and it's complicated to write code for them).

Parsing a string with e.g. a euro amount such as `"-1234,58"` in it can be parsed to the `long` `-123458` using:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(-?)(\\s*\\d*)(?:,(\\d{2}))?$");
var m = p.matcher("2273370,68");
long amount;
if (m.matches()) {
  amount =
    (m.group(1).equals("-") ? -1L : 1L) * (
    100 * (m.group(2).isEmpty() ? 0 : Long.parseLong(m.group(2))) +
    (m.group(3) != null ? Long.parseLong(m.group(3)) : 0L));
} else throw new NumberFormatException();
```

Any attempt to use `Double.parseDouble` will get you into that rounding trouble and you randomly lose or gain a cent. Run a bank like that and you might get into a wee bit of trouble :)